# How can I hide <div> elements from view but stil have them take up space with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
   <div class="block-border">
       <div class="grid-select">
            <div class="clearfix">
               ...
               ...
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

On the form area are controls which are populated with data once the screen loads. While the population is still ongoing I have a variable $scope.loading which has a non zero value. When the load finishes this value will be zero.

Is there a way that I could hide the controls on the `<div class="grid-select">` so they are not visible. Note that I still want them to use up space and I still want to show the block-border DIV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try css' `visibility: hidden;` something like:

```
<style>
 .hidden{
   visibility:hidden;
 }
</style>

<div class="grid-select" ng-class="{'hidden': loading!=0 }">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/YJ2R7/

Answer (score 1):

**Angular markup:**
`<div class="grid-select" ng-class="{'isLoading': loading}">`

**CSS**

`.grid-select {visibility: hidden;}

.isLoading {visibility: visible;}`