# How can I show and hide an element with AngularJS while having it still use space?

Tags: angularjs

I have a button in AngularJS. It's in a row of other buttons.  How can I show and hide this button but still have it use space? I tried using ng-show but then when the button is hidden it uses no space and all the other buttons around it move.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904815/how-can-i-hide-div-elements-from-view-but-stil-have-them-take-up-space-with-an?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your CSS, target the element like this:

```
.my-element.ng-hide {
    display: block!important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

(You might want `inline-block` or something else for the display, the important part is to override the `none` default value of `ng-hide`)

You can then use `ng-show="showMyElement"` as an attribute as per usual